# PHP ob_start("ob_gzhandler") with ob_clean error

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.1

I'm using PHP 7.1 and I'm using the following pseudo-code to generate my website:

```
<?php

    ob_start("ob_gzhandler", 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);

    try{        
        echo "<h1>My awesome webpage!</h1>";
        ... more code that can throw exceptions...
        echo "<h2>Welcome to my awesome webpage!</h2>";
    }catch(\Throwable $e){
        ob_clean();
        echo "My awesome webpage crashed :((";
    }
```

When no exceptions is thrown, all works as expected: the website is outputted and compressed. [You can see the result here](https://everyfad.com/phpBug/ok)

But, when an exception is thrown, something unexpected happens ([link to the result](https://everyfad.com/phpBug/error)): as desired, only the text outputted after ob_clean() is sent to the browser, but it cannot decode it correctly.

The problem seems related to the fact that the browser doesn't recognize the output of the page as compressed.

Digging into the issue, it seems that, when `ob_clean` is called, the header    `content-encoding` is not sent to the browser. To confirm this hypothesis, I tried to manually set that header, and everything works as expected ([link](https://everyfad.com/phpBug/error2)).

```
<?php

    ob_start("ob_gzhandler", 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);

    try{        
        echo "<h1>My awesome webpage!</h1>";
        throw new \Exception("Whops");
        echo "<h2>Welcome to my awesome webpage!</h2>";
    }catch(\Throwable $e){
        ob_clean();
        header('content-encoding:gzip'); //Why PHP?... WHYYY?!?!?
        echo "My awesome webpage crashed :((";
    }
```

My question is the following: since ob_start("ob_gzhandler") doesn't always use gzip compression (e.g. when the browser doesn't support it), my work around of manually setting the header is not viable. How can I achieve the same result without using some horrible hack?

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug?

Comment: "How can I achieve the same result without using some horrible hack?"  To be honest, if I were in your shoes, I wouldn't use ob_gzhandler at all.  I'd configure your httpd/proxy to do the gzipping for you, rather than trying to handle it in PHP.

Comment: @Andrea I'm not sure if it's a bug of if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @FrankFarmer Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Spotlight Well, if it's not a bug, bugs.php.net won't scold you…

Answer (score 0):

i guess a quickfix would be

```
if(false!==stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] ??'','gzip')){
    header('content-encoding:gzip'); //Why PHP?... WHYYY?!?!?
}
```

or if you're worried about a (theoretical) incompatible compression that happens to have `gzip` in the name,

```
if(in_array('gzip',array_map('strtolower',array_map('trim',explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']??''))),true))
```

still feels hackish, though...